# previous command in R console

Tags: r, console, editor

I would like to retrieve the previous command in my R console that started with a certain character.  For example, i can just press the up key to get the last command.  However, I'd like the last command that started with `xyz` for example. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: ahh, i see. so just use emacs commands. got it. thanks!

Comment: This would be very useful indeed, since I find myself wishing to invoke a previous command very frequently too. We need the equivalent of f8 in DOS and like someone said below Ctrl+R in Unix. I'm using RGui x64 on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you're on a linux distro, you can press ctrl+R and start typing, and then ctrl+R to toggle through search matches.

you can also do, history(pattern="^xyz"), but this would require an additional copy.